# Chromebook App jQuery and some links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-app, chromebook

Before I get into this, I would like to tell you I have no expedience with json's and little experience with how Chromebooks run.

Ok, so I am creating an app for a chromebook, where It acts as a browser/mock google thing I made. In Google, It runs fine,  but when I put it into an app, something always messes up. I don't know what the problem is, but Ive tinkered with it alot and nothing works. see code below for further refrence

Press Ctrl-Shift-Alt to Open the menu, once the code has started

In the App: https://drive.google.com/a/lpsk12.org/file/d/0Bxq6mhn1Ff4ZeFl6S1U0WlNJMGM/view?usp=sharing

---

It is Either a manifest problem, or it is a error with chrome. How do I solve this?
Here is the code:

---

Manifest:

```
{
"name": "Hallo",
"description": "Testing",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"app": {
 "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
 }
 },
 "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
 }
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
 chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
 'outerBounds': {
  'width': 400,
  'height': 500
 }
 });
 });
```

Window.html:

https://drive.google.com/a/lpsk12.org/file/d/0Bxq6mhn1Ff4ZSHd0RmdibVVJOTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Its supposed to look like this: https://drive.google.com/a/lpsk12.org/file/d/0Bxq6mhn1Ff4ZZ1h4eFdLVEVxS0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have any error logs?

Comment: @abielita No, its just that the url in the html don't work, and when I copy/ pasted the jQuery, it still didn't work